# How does the forwarding of the packets with these destination addresses occur?

Tags: networking, routing, forwarding

I'm currently studying routing and in a few days I'll have a test about it. On my coursebook there's this exercise:

**A router has the following routing table and the following configuration of interfaces:**

[image]

1. Interface 1: 131.175.21.254, 255.255.255.0
2. Interface 2: 131.175.12.254, 255.255.255.0

**Describe how does the forwarding of the packets with the following destination addresses occur:**

**a.** 131.175.21.86
**b.** 131.175.16.65
**c.** 131.180.21.78
**d.** 200.45.21.84

My book is not written in english, so I had to translate it from italian.
My first question is: what exactly is First Hop? It's never been mentioned on my book, not even once.

Anyway, not knowing what it actually is, I just assumed it is the Next Hop address.
Also, I know that in a routing table the Network address 0.0.0.0 stands for the "default route": when a destination address doesn't match with any of the records in a routing table, the one with the network 0.0.0.0 is taken.
But what is the First Hop 0.0.0.0? Where is the packet actually forwarded in this case?

My answers on this exercise are the following:
**a.** The packet is forwarded to **131.175.21.86**. This happens because the Interface 1's Net ID the same as the Net-ID of this IP Address, so a direct forwarding occurs.
**b.** **131.175.21.2**, because the Destination IP address matches the 2nd record of the routing table
**c.** **131.175.21.4**, because the Destination IP address matches the 6th record of the routing table
**d.** **0.0.0.0** because the Destination IP address doesn't match with any of the records in the routing table.

Is it correct?  The Interface 2 has also never been used in this exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is potentially not displayed in your textbook but is displayed in most routing tables are additional implicit routes for attached interfaces as well as the typically found interface intended to be used for each route. [An interesting look into how a device routes packet is here.](http://academy.delmar.edu/Courses/download/CiscoIOS/CiscoRoutingTable2_Lookup.pdf)

A typical Cisco IOS Routing table might look like this (*for your example assuming routes were entered statically*):

```
RouterA#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
<text omitted>
Gateway of last resort is not set
 131.0.0.0/16 is subnetted, 9 subnets
C 131.175.21.0/24 is directly connected, Interface1
C 131.175.12.0/24 is directly connected, Interface2
S 131.175.15.0/24 [120/1] via 131.175.21.1, 00:00:00, Interface1
S 131.175.16.0/24 [120/1] via 131.175.21.2, 00:00:00, Interface1
S 131.175.17.0/24 [120/1] via 131.175.21.3, 00:00:00, Interface1
S 131.180.23.0/24 [120/1] via 131.175.21.4, 00:00:00, Interface1
S 131.180.18.0/24 [120/1] via 131.175.21.4, 00:00:00, Interface1
S 131.180.21.0/24 [120/1] via 131.175.21.4, 00:00:00, Interface1
S 131.180.0.0/24 [120/1] via 131.175.21.5, 00:00:00, Interface1
S* 0.0.0.0/0 is directly connected, Loopback0
```

Each route in the table has the network address and the bits used for matching (in this case the first 24 bits which is the first 3 octets), a "next hop" address that the route will send the packet to, as well as an interface the device knows that that hop exists on.

So you can see that the layer 3 device proceeds to use the network mask to attempt to match the leftmost bits of each packet it receives to the appropriate route. It proceeds from top to bottom typically sorting the directly connected routes first, followed by the strictest network mask routes (*e.g. /30 routes before a /24 route*).

What happens when there is no proper default route configured as per your routing table above? Well it depends on how the device is configured. We'll cover an interesting example before going to the question d example. Suppose a packet was received for the destination address **131.175.18.1**. Where would it go? It would first find the parent route **131.0.0.0/16** as a match and proceed to check the children. After checking all child routes and not finding a match, it will then take 1 of 2 actions. If the device is configured **classless** it will attempt to use a default route as above. If the device is configured **classful** it will simply drop the packet.

In your question, the IP address does not match any parent route and in fact is actually a [class C address instead of a Class B address](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/ip.htm) as we've seen so far. The device would likely proceed immediately to the default route but there isn't sufficient information to indicate that the default route is attached to a specific interface or a specific next hop router. From the information provided above, it appears to not be configured so the router would drop the packet as if the default route were configured to the Loopback address (*as I added to the routing table for clarity - however would likely not appear there*).

Answer (score 0):

First hop is the machine/IP address that the packet is sent to. If you imagine a traceroute (which shows all the machines a packet traverses) the first hop is the first line of the traceroute. Indeed, the first hop is the next hop - First hop applies to a packet originating on the device, while next hop could be a forwarded packet as seen by a router.

A routing table with a next hop of 0.0.0.0 is unusual - this is probably a point-to-point interface eg ppp - normally each line of a routing table has an interface associated with it - that seems to be missing - but the default route must be a 1:1 mapping so if information is sent out that interface there is only 1 interface it could be communicating with on the other side.

Your answers are correct.